# Why doesn't Chromium get quicker updates?

Tags: security, chromium

I'm running 10.04 and i'm still only  on v12 even though we've just had v14 pushed out by Google and on 3 Sept a big update to v13 that revoked the Diginotar certificates. I was running a ppa at one point but I can't remember when. Even so this state of affairs hazardous.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using Chromium ? You can download the official Google Chrome v14 from: http://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other. I prefer to use repositories where possible.

Comment: You can also set up a repository that gives you the latest stable, beta or development release of Chromium. Those are the PPAs belonging to this team on Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily

For what it's worth, downloading the official Chrome deb package from Google also sets you up with a repository for updates. It does it for you when you install the package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, the last 2 Chromium updates I tried to push out failed verification (bug 819991 and bug 834922).  Recently, the person who was "maintaining" Chromium in Ubuntu also left the project.  I plan on uploading Chromium 14 as soon as possible.

Comment: Chromium 14 is now in Lucid and later except on armel, hopefully we can get that updated soon as well.